# Ajax form Submit vizualizing the php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

This is the js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#create-admin").submit(function(e)
    {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        if(forms == null)
        {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "crud_admin.php",
                dataType: "html",
                data: $("#create-admin").serialize()

            }).done(function(data){
                toastr.success(data, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
            })
        }
        /**/
    })
})
```

this is the form

```
<form id="create-admin" class="needs-validation" autocomplete="off" action="crud_admin.php" method="POST" novalidate> ... </form>
```

this is the crud_admin.php
vars and db stuff
.................. the response

```
 if($db_connection->query($sql_add)){

        echo "success";
    }else {
        echo "fail";}
```

When i click on submit the form all data goes to db, and it redirect me to the page crud_admin.php 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psoS1.png)

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` to the top of the `submit` function.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); prevents the submition now dont even do nothing when i submit the form. @msg

Comment: Prevents *normal* submission of the form, the javascript submission should still work. Check the browser's debug tools to confirm it's making a request, and that there's no error in the console, then the problem must be in the `toastr` call.

Comment: No request, and no erros on console, even trade toaster for a simple alert also not working. @msg

Comment: The ajax call is inside `if(forms == null)` but it will never be `null`, it will be a `NodeList` that could be empty. Please add a working example. Does the class at some point get removed?

Comment: i agree with @msg, i updated my answer to check if the form has desired class.

Comment: Thx @msg i found the error, was on my custom form validatation, it supose to remove needs-validation to validated, good eye on the if thx very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, how @msg says, try to use `preventDefault()` method to prevent common behavior of the form. Try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', "#create-admin", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).hasClass('needs-validation'))
        {
           //Make validation before the ajax request
           $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "crud_admin.php",
              data: $(this).serialize()
           }).done(function(data){
                toastr.success(data, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
           })
        }
        /**/
    })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); prevents the submition now dont even do nothing when  i submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try add a line of code using function preventDefault.  It should place before var forms = ......

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Hope it can help.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); prevents the submition now dont even do nothing when i submit the form.